# Discover the minimum possible time

Tags: scala, gatling

a simple question but hard for me to get it done

```
scn.inject(x over y)
```

The question is how to (automatically) find out the minimum `y` at which the simulation is passing.

I could not find the solution reading the docs.

Edit: Maybe somehow repeat the test while reducing `y`?

Comment: You probably meant you were looking for a _maximum_ **y** your application can handle. Otherwise a 'minimum' is a 0 - a no load event.

Comment: **y** is the time range in this case. E.g. I would like in what (minimum) time **y** i can handle 100000 request.